# Is "deliberation" or "deliberations" correct when done over multiple topics?

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Are these sentences correct?

1. Contemporary deliberation on American culture, economy, politics in the 20th and 21st century?
2. Contemporary deliberation**s** on American culture, economy, and politics in the 20th and 21st century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence number **1** makes perfect sense. For better style, I'd write:

*Contemporary deliberation on American culture, economy **and** politics in the 20th and 21st century.*

EDIT: "*Deliberation***s**" is better for this title, as I understand it to be, since it looks like many ideas will be expressed.

Comment: Sentence 2 should read: Contemporary deliberations...Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is a sentence as the term is commonly understood because neither contains a finite verb. However, both *deliberation* and *deliberations* might be found, depending on context.